# How to correctly JOIN 3 tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I am trying to create a database that contains users (general) and two more tables, that is: male / female choice. This will be used for dating, more specifically the fact that a girl votes for a boy, a boy for a girl. If their choices are overlapping, it means that they fit together.

I do not know if I approached the topic well, but so far I have built the following code:

```
USERS:
| ID (PRIMARY) |  NAME  | GENDER |
|       1      | Man1   | Male   |
|       2      | Man2   | Male   |
|       3      | Woman1 | Female |
|       4      | Woman2 | Female |
```

```
Woman_Result
| ID (PRIMARY) | ID_PERSON | ID_CHOOSE |
|       1      |    3      |    1      |
|       2      |    3      |    2      |
|       3      |    4      |    1      |
```

```
Man_Result
| ID (PRIMARY) | ID_PERSON | ID_CHOOSE |
|       1      |    1      |    4      |
|       2      |    2      |    1      |
```

So the match of those people is only: Man1 and Woman2

```
SELECT  w.*, m.*
    FROM  Man_Result AS m
    JOIN  Woman_Result AS w
    WHERE w.ID_CHOOSE = m.ID_PERSON AND m.ID_CHOOSE = w.ID_PERSON
```

OUTPUT:

```
| ID | ID_PERSON | ID_CHOOSE | ID | ID_PERSON | ID_CHOOSE |
| 1  |     1     |     4     | 1  |     4     |     1     |
```

So its working, but how i can connect it to my USERS table to get those output:

```
NAME | NAME
Man1 | Woman2
```

I have combined with something like this, but I don't know completely how to combine it to make it work :)

```
SELECT USERS.NAME
FROM USERS
INNER JOIN Woman_Result ON USERS.ID = Woman_Result.ID_PERSON
INNER JOIN Man_Result ON USERS.ID = Man_Result.ID_PERSON
```

-- EDIT --

If I wanted to add "ID_CHOOSE2", "ID_CHOOSE3" etc to each user, what kind of query would I have to create for it to be correct? I Tried use "OR":

```
ON w.ID_CHOOSE OR w.ID_CHOOSE2 = m.ID_PERSON AND m.ID_CHOOSE OR m.ID_CHOOSE2 = w.ID_PERSON
```

And

```
ON (w.ID_CHOOSE = m.ID_PERSON AND m.ID_CHOOSE = w.ID_PERSON)
OR (w.ID_CHOOSE2 = m.ID_PERSON AND m.ID_CHOOSE2 = w.ID_PERSON)
```

But the second example only compares the same columns, and my point is that it compares each to each as in the example with one person

My code: https://onecompiler.com/mysql/3xz4552uv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must join 2 copies of `USERS` to your current join.
The 1st copy will return the man's name and the 2nd will return the woman's name:

```
SELECT um.NAME AS man_name,
       uw.NAME AS woman_name
FROM Man_Result AS m JOIN Woman_Result AS w 
ON w.ID_CHOOSE = m.ID_PERSON AND m.ID_CHOOSE = w.ID_PERSON
JOIN USERS AS um ON m.ID_PERSON = um.ID
JOIN USERS AS uw ON w.ID_PERSON = uw.ID;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f64fee58f03dc2d380affc3c6a6bcea5).

Comment: Hello, i edited my post and add choose2 to check. Can You Help me?

Comment: @Karmay if you have a new requirement you should ask a new question and not change the current question because this way you invalidate the answers of the original question.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so this is the query that you should be using to get your results back if you decided to this in **ONE TABLE** called `matches`

```
id  uid1  uid2
1   1     4
2   2     1
3   3     1
4   3     2
5   4     1
6   1     2
```

The matches table has `id`, `uid1`, `uid2`, and a primary key which is the combination of `(uid1,uid2)`

Then your query would be something like this

```
SELECT
    C.name, D.name
FROM matches A
INNER JOIN matches B 
    ON A.uId1 = B.uId2 AND A.uId2 = B.pId1 AND B.Id > A.Id
INNER JOIN users C ON A.uId1 = C.Id
INNER JOIN users D ON A.uId2 = D.Id
```

Or you can do it with `CTE` like the following which is a bit faster:

```
;WITH DATA AS (
SELECT
    A.*
FROM matches A
INNER JOIN matches B 
    ON A.uId1 = B.uId2 AND A.uId2 = B.uId1 AND B.Id > A.Id )

SELECT
    C.name, D.name
FROM DATA A
INNER JOIN users C ON A.uId1 = C.Id
INNER JOIN users D ON A.uId2 = D.Id
```

If you don't have the ability to change your SQL table and how it is structured I would do it using a `temp variable` like the following:

```
DECLARE @STARTDATA TABLE ( uid1 int, uid2 int, primary key (uid1, uid2) )

INSERT INTO @STARTDATA (uid1, uid2)
SELECT
    A.uid1, A.uid2
FROM matches A
INNER JOIN matches B 
    ON A.uId1 = B.uId2 AND A.uId2 = B.uId1 AND B.Id > A.Id

SELECT
    C.name, D.name
FROM @STARTDATA A
INNER JOIN users C ON A.uId1 = C.Id
INNER JOIN users D ON A.uId2 = D.Id
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. :) I edited my topic and have next one question (choose2). Do You have any idea?